# Are "Has anyone installed Ubuntu (version) on a (Notebook brand/model) successfully" questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Well, the title says it all. I have a laptop on which I could't install 9.04 and was wondering if anyone tried 10.10 on one. Are this kind of questions on topic?

I know there used to be a compatibility page on the ubuntu site, but it's really out of date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been religiously closing those as duplicates of this question: [Which computers are guaranteed to work with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work-with-ubuntu)

Ultimately those questions are Too Localized and will only spawn numerous of posts about "Is X machine compatible with Ubuntu" All of which duplicate the responses given in the above linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the information located on http://webapps.ubuntu.com/certification/ .
Toward the bottom of the page there is information about specific machines we have conducted testing on. This should be the best location for the information you seek.

~JFo

Comment: Thanks. I've already checked that page and my laptop is not listed. Sadly, I didn't check _before_ buying...
I'll see how the install works and publish my results.